# How to debug errors in bundle.js and main.chunk.js?

Tags: reactjs, express, debugging, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have some errors in my console that I cannot seem to effectively debug.

[image: Console error message]

They may be related to adding an express server and running it concurrently with the react app. The react app was working fine before I added the express server but is now not working at all (white screen).

I don't know where to start since these files are obviously huge and for example searching for "<" in them returns hundreds of results. **How do I take a first step towards understanding what the problem is?**

Thanks

Comment: Check out your network tab where these JS files are being fetched. It appears that they are returning HTML and not JS. This can happen if a web server is misconfigured or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It's browser issue reported to Google team as well ( in my case ). I had same issue with chrome version (Version 92.0.4515.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)). Please update your browser and the issue will go away.